# Discord.py running an async function on demand

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to run the following async function at a certain time.

```
async def test(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(730099302130516058)
    await channel.send('hello')
```

I am testing it with
`asyncio.run(test(bot.get_context))`. But when I run it I get `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'` And I have tested this and it means channel is equal to none so it cant send the message as channel = "None".

Now when I do the following it works. But of course I have to run the command test

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(730099302130516058)
    await channel.send('hello')
```

I plan to use schedule to run it at the times I required but will still call the function in a similar way.
Is there a way to call an async function and pass ctx correctly?

Entire Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

TOKEN = "Token Would Be Here"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')

async def test(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(730099302130516058)
    await channel.send('hello')

asyncio.run(test(bot.get_context))
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the rest of your code? Ideally, a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It looks like the bot is not connected when `bot.get_channel` is called, resulting in `None` being returned.

Comment: @Benjin I have added a the rest of the code. You should be able to see that the bot is connected. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bot.get_channel()` is returning `None` because the bot has not yet connected, meaning it cannot see any channels. You need to add `await bot.wait_until_ready()`, which will force the bot to wait until it is connected before continuing.

You also don't need to pass `ctx` as you never use it.

`discord.py` also already has it's own event loop that you can use. You can add the coroutine to the loop using `bot.loop.create_task()`.

```
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "Token Would Be Here"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')

async def test():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    channel = bot.get_channel(370935329353367568)
    await channel.send('hello')

bot.loop.create_task(test())
bot.run(TOKEN)
```