# get_channel gives nonetype in loop

Tags: discord.py

me and my friend both don't know what's going on with get_channel not working. i am currently working on a loop and need it to be in a specific channel.

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=2)
async def datetask():
    tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
    berlin_current_datetime = datetime.now(tz)
    channel = client.get_channel(894586024607494144)

    await channel.send(f"current date {berlin_current_datetime}")

datetask.start()
```

any help would be grateful, i looked all trough this site but nothing worked.
(seconds set to 2 just to test)

Comment: The bot needs to be connected before `client.get_channel` will return anything but `None`. You need to add `await bot.wait_until_ready()`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794674/discord-py-running-an-async-function-on-demand/62796967#62796967)

Comment: okay, i'll try it rn

Comment: thank you so much! it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might as well want to Read this:
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2282